# Quicktime screen recording creates a green movie

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video, quicktime, screen-capture

I tried creating a screencast on my OSX 10.8.5 MacBook pro, using QuickTime. This has worked before, but when I try it now I get:

[image]

The problem happens both on an external screen and on the retina display on the Mac. I've [Googled the issue](http://www.baldengineer.com/blog/2013/04/22/osx-fixing-the-green-screen-issue-when-capturing-your-desktop-with-quicktime-or-other/) and tried installing [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io/), but it wouldn't work on my external monitor.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you running 10.7 or 10.7.5, and what version of QuickTime? I am running 10.7.5, and QuickTime 10.1 and this functionality works fine.

Comment: My bad, it's OSX 10.8.5, not 10.7. Quicktime version is 10.2 (603.17).

Answer (score 1):

The (Ugly) solution that works is installing [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io/), Choosing "Integrated Only" and screencasting my laptop monitor without any external monitor.

It's is ugly indeed - will welcome any proper solution.

[image]